# Trouble downloading GTA5 on XBOX360

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I have attempted to download GTA5 several times. I have a 60GB hard drive on my XBOX360. I also bought a 32GB 3.0 USB flash drive, still says the game was restarted due to a problem with storage device. I did a factory reset on my XBOX360, and cleared cache. Cloud is disabled. I'm at a loss. Someone please help.

Comment: How are you downloading the game?

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the USB, it won't work as Xbox storage straight out of the box.
 Plug it into your PC, open up “My computer,” right-click on the USB device, and select “Format.” Format the USB flash drive to FAT32. Make sure to save any files before doing this, as formatting will erase all data on the USB flash drive.